# Kabbalat shabbat at home face west or southeast?

Tags: kabbalat-shabbat

One davening Kabbalat shabbat alone at home, does he face west for Bo'i Kallah/Lekha dodi ? or does he just face southeast indoors for the entire kabbalat shabbat service?

Comment: He should go out to the field and face the setting sun. Why is he indoors at all?

Answer (score 0):

In Ishei Yisroel 36, footnote 32, it is bright from R’ Chaim Kanievski zt”l Mazzola or should face the door when davening alone.

Comment: face the door when davening alone even if its not west ?

Comment: Yes that’s what he says

Comment: Ashaynem dank for that clarification. Much appreciated.

Comment: So if one is already facing the door, then there will be no turning I suppose